# How do I get the fields of form attached with a content type as token?

Tags: 7, forms, rules, emails, tokens

I do not know is it possible or not. I have a content type for creating tickets. I have a form attached to content type which contains ticket state and ticket assignee fields as drop down. Now I want to create a Rule when state of ticket updated then send an email to ticket creater. The problem is that I could not find the state field values as token.

Comment: `i could not find the status field values as token` is your status the `ticket state` ?

Comment: Yes, it is the state.

Comment: In your Rule, what **react** on event are you using?

Comment: Could understand what are you saying

Comment: @NoSssweat asked which event are you using in the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want send email after state field changes by Rule:

You should:

1. Create a new rule that will react to the *After updating existing content* event
2. Use the following condition:
   Data comparison: *node:field-your-field*(maybe field-state) and *node-unchanged:field-your-field*
   Select *Negate: FALSE*
3. Create the action
4. Send the email

Comment: Can you please how can i get the author email address who commented at last in rules?

Comment: @Iqbal  you're welcome, please ask it in another question.